# If statement always returning false while trying to detect the color of a pixel

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, image-processing, python-imaging-library

So I'm restarting working on a project with pygame, and I'm trying to make the background of a 50x50 image transparent (originally colored black), but I'm unable to change the color of the pixel

Here is the code I have now:

```
image2BCleared = Image.open("C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/PythonGame/image_player.png")
imageArray = numpy.array(image2BCleared)
width, height = image2BCleared.size
transparent = (0, 0, 0, 0)
newDataItem = (0,0,0,0)

for i in range(0, width):
    for j in range(0, height):
        newDataItem = imageArray[i][j]
        if newDataItem.all == (0, 0, 0, 255):
            imageArray[i][j] = transparent
            print(imageArray[i][j])
dirpath = os.getcwd()
im = Image.fromarray(imageArray)
im.save("img2.png", "PNG")
```

the when I run the program, there is no output from the print statement.

For some reason, it always goes to the "else" statement event though the content on the array is the same (I used this code):

```
imageArray = numpy.array(image2BCleared)
width, height = image2BCleared.size
newData = []
counterI = 0
counterJ = 0
for item in imageArray:
    if item.all == (0, 0, 0, 225):
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
        print("true")
    else:
        newData.append(item)
print(newData)
```

output:

```
[array([[  0,   0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0, 255],
      [  0,   0,   0, 255],
#fowllowed by other pixels from different colors but nothing transparent
```

basically "newData" has a lot of slots that contains (0, 0, 0, 255).
I'm not very familiar with image processing so it might be some really basic error but I don't really see any logic problems (turn picture into array of pixels, compare pixels to a certain value, if color == (0, 0, 0, 255) add a transparent pixel to newData else add the pixel to newData)

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have 225 instead of 255 in the if statement. Typo?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out but unfortunately that's not it... still not able to get it to work after correcting it

Comment: Perhaps it's because you're comparing a _tuple_ to a _list_, even though they have the same contents?  Try printing `item.all` in the loop.

Comment: never heard about a "tuple" in programming101 before, I'll look it up. thanks

Comment: I don't think `.all` is doing what you think it's doing

Comment: yep. I didn't know that the variable type "tuple" existed

Comment: Please don’t edit the solution into the question. The answer below contains the solution.

Comment: Oh okay. sorry about that! removing it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the .all attribute of a numpy array.  all is actually a method of numpy's array class and you would use it as:

```
my_array = np.array([1, 2, 3])
my_array.all()
```

This would return true if all the elements of my_array are boolean True.

Therefore your code is comparing a method object to a tuple, so of course they are not equal.

Instead, try this.  item is an array.  You are trying to compare to a tuple.  You will need to either convert one to the other or compare element wise.

Any of the below should work, which I've given in my order of preference.  Note that where you use the np.array() method you could pass it the tuple (0, 0, 00, 255) or the list [0, 0, 0, 255].

```
all(item == (0, 0, 0, 255))
(item == (0, 0, 0, 255)).all()
tuple(item) == (0, 0, 0, 255)
all(item == np.array((0, 0, 0, 255)))
(item == np.array([0, 0, 0, 255])).all()
all([a==b for (a,b) in zip(item, (0, 0, 0, 255))])
all([item[i] == (0, 0, 0, 255)[i] for i in range(4)])
```

EDIT:

Adding one more edit since the title of the question might lead people here with different problems.
If you are expecting two objects to match but they don't, try the following steps.

1. Check the types of each using type(object_1) and type(object_2) to verify that they are the same.  You can print these individually to compare, or print the result of type(object_1) == type(object_2).
2. If they are iterable (e.g. lists, tuples, arrays, dicts, and others), iterate over them and check each entry matches.  You can print the contents of two arrays side by side using:

   ```
   for a, b in zip(object_1, object_2):
       print(a, b)
   ```

Comment: It worked! I changed it to tuple(newDataItem) == (0, 0, 0, 255) . Thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure.  I've since updated my answer to give a little more detail, so check back for a fuller answer later.  Also, if it solves your problem a little "accept as right" never goes amiss ;)